# Auto capitalization of the noun "I" on post submit

Tags: feature-request, editor

We all want to make SO as good as possible and waste as little time of the people answering as possible. When I look at the tab labeled "Newest" I find that a good portion of the questions do not capitalize the letter "I". Therefore, anyone wishing to edit the question is bombarded with the task of having to fix all of the caps. This takes a good chunk of time when one would rather be fixing the things that really matter, like wording and spelling. This could be avoided by simply using a Regex to replace all of the lowercase "i"s with the capital version. (Note for the SO team): The Regex would be placed just before the question content was posted. This would enable people to spend more time answering the question than fixing it. We could display a notification saying: "Please remember to capitalize and spell correctly." if the service is required to make changes. Also, we can put them on parole if they have so many questions that had to be fixed, until they understand.

Example: [I m facing an issue with control structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48609759/i-m-facing-an-issue-with-control-structures)

Example: [Angular Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48609758/angular-response-for-preflight-has-invalid-http-status-code-404)

Example: [Copy an array to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48609887/copy-an-array-to-another)

Example: [Iterating though Items using Javascript inside a UIWebView ? how Can i achieve it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48609908/iterating-though-items-using-javascript-inside-a-uiwebview-how-can-i-achieve-i)

Example: [collatz conjecture count how many have the length 111](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48609916/collatz-conjecture-count-how-many-have-the-length-111)

Example: [SQL: Get the row with maximum nested table entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48609933/sql-get-the-row-with-maximum-nested-table-entries)

Example: [Cannot Find name "LocationAccuracy"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48609941/cannot-find-name-locationaccuracy)

Example: [vue component data watch outside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48609963/vue-component-data-watch-outside)

Example: [need to plot graphs and they need to vary according to what the user selects from the dropdown menu or checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48609975/need-to-plot-graphs-and-they-need-to-vary-according-to-what-the-user-selects-fro)

Example: [How to update data in mongowith spring boot and mongo and react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48609998/how-to-update-data-in-mongowith-spring-boot-and-mongo-and-react)

Example: [How to implement "all check" button on AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48610010/how-to-implement-all-check-button-on-angularjs)

Example: [Use First() and Repeat() without restarting whole stream RxJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48610022/use-first-and-repeat-without-restarting-whole-stream-rxjs)

Example: [How i can add data into QlLinePlot thai is a QML wrapper for QCustomPlot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48610025/how-i-can-add-data-into-qllineplot-thai-is-a-qml-wrapper-for-qcustomplot)

Example: [How to Show scrollable panel in Unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48610030/how-to-show-scrollable-panel-in-unity3d)

Example: [Callback to solve unhandled promise, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48610078/callback-to-solve-unhandled-promise-why)

Example: [How to read a text file with multiple paragraphs from assets folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48610072/how-to-read-a-text-file-with-multiple-paragraphs-from-assets-folder)

Example: [Using ajax in laravel with cors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48610100/using-ajax-in-laravel-with-cors)

Example: [libpcap c/c++ callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48610118/libpcap-c-c-callback-function)

Example: [Parallel screencapture with robot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48610158/parallel-screencapture-with-robot)

Example: [ruby on rails rmagick can't use,, cloud9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48610177/ruby-on-rails-rmagick-cant-use-cloud9)

Example: [Warning issue when installing Hadoop 2.8.2 on Mac OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48610184/warning-issue-when-installing-hadoop-2-8-2-on-mac-os)

Example: [javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException for hotmail account android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48610232/javax-mail-authenticationfailedexception-for-hotmail-account-android)

Comment: Most probably because you are claiming that a simple regex would fix the problem. Regex is not meant for natural language processing. Any attempt to do so will result in false positives. The most common problem I can imaging is that everytime I refer to a variable i it will be capitalized. Not every i is a misspelled noun.

Comment: Finnaly someone is honest. @BDL

Comment: But the evidence is overwelming is it not? @BDL

Comment: I, for one, have downvoted because this sort of auto-correction doesn't work well in general (cf. Maroun's answer). That said, pinging other people with example after example every single minute gets obnoxious very quickly -- please don't do that from now on.

Comment: Supposed to be an example of how often this happens. @duplode

Comment: That’s the second time you’ve made reference to someone “finally” or “at last” being honest in as many posts. Where’s that coming from? What do you mean by it?

Comment: The second reason is that your habit of actively annoying everyone who participates in the discussing here by pinging them all the time. (in the deleted comment thread under the question, now me in two comments. If you have something to say, say it. But please think before writing, then write one comment and ping me once.

Comment: @TheOneWhoMade: What did user202729 do to hurt you, to deserve you pestering them with comment after comment after comment after comment after comment after comment? Look, we know you **abhor** people's failure to capitalize "I" but please don't take your frustration with this out on others.

Comment: Sorry. I will think of that next time. @BoltClock

Comment: That has nothing to do with honesty, just your perception of what’s useful. Try to choose your words more carefully, accusing people of being dishonest for no reason is very poor form

Comment: Sigh........... @Clive

Comment: But you don't have any evidence that it won't cause any false positive (detect `i` in code, for example) Also... let the askers have some work.

Comment: @user202729 as I said to Maroun, I will construct the regex myself if necessary. I want this feature that much.

Comment: I’m assuming that means “Sigh, what a daft thing that was to do, yes I should stop it immediately”. Good for you.

Comment: You got it. @Clive

Comment: Then your "research" only shows that there are a lot of cases where I is misspelled. Noone here claims that this isn't the case. We say "Yes, there are a lot of misspelled i that should be capitalized, but your solution will produce too many false-positives.". Your reply is to show us more posts where I should be capitalized. I suggest you write a regex (as you claim it should be simple) and run it against the data explorer data (for example all posts added in the last week). Then check how often the capitalization was correct and how often it wasn't and report that back.

Comment: You be back here in a week. @BDL

Comment: Constructing personal unit tests, @BDL

Comment: i dont think its' as important to rectify as misuse of apostrophe's.

Comment: A warning might be a good idea.

Comment: I have made a Regex+Javascript functioning example. It only capitilizes outside of code blocks. No external API's @BDL

Comment: Would you like to see it? @BDL

Comment: I checked a few already.

Comment: Rebel. But thanks. What I am trying to say is that there are a few things that could be fixed easily. @MartinJames

Comment: That's nice. Can you evaluate it? Please provide the full research, including the data set used and the final metrics. Preferably in terms of accuracy,  precision, and recall.

Comment: Full research? My own. @E_net4

Comment: [parse with regex, yeah, sure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/839601)

Comment: I tried "i like that" and "So do i". Nothing gets capitalized. "The variable i contains a running index", "While looking at section i - iv", "I want to filter all letters from i to z" capitalizes i where it shouldn't be capitalized. I'm out now since you are not willing to accept that regex should not be used to parse natural language. There might be ways to achieve such a detector with machine learning, but even then I highly doubt that it would run with a low enough error rate that it should be applied automatically.

Comment: The code can easily be adapted to include anything that you may want to not be capitalized to not be capitalized. @BDL

Comment: So you just want us to iteratively hard-code new cases as they come up? Who is going to (want to) maintain that?

Comment: Maybe I do. @E_net4 or it could be automated based on edits.

Comment: The key issue is the idea that the formula "can be easily adapted to include anything that you may want to not be capitalized." Anything is a huge category! No one, not even your self, will be able to think of all edge cases. It will be a constant "Whoops, it capitalized this i where it wasn't supposed to be, let's add another exception to the rule", endless meta posts reporting bugs with the i auto correct, and uncountable posts where the incorrect auto correct doesn't get caught by the OP and the post is just wrong with a capitalized i where it shouldn't be.

Comment: I really should not have linked this to so many posts. That made it a target to huge crowds.

Comment: Having a large crowd look at your question should be helpful to you, to help you judge the usefulness of your suggestion as received by the community. Right now there are 41 down votes and 1 upvote on your question; thereby, of the people who have seen your question and have enough understanding and opinion to care about the feature you are suggesting, 41 out of 42 people do not consider it useful. (I am assuming that that is their reason for downvoting, as you have researched the question and what you want is quite clear, and I personally downvoted because I see this feature as harmful.)

Answer (score 21):

There's no simple regex that handles all cases.

What if I want to describe the character "i" that's matched by the regex `[d-k]`? I want to be able to just write "i", without surrounding it with back-ticks (since it's not really a code).

If you feel there are many "i"s that need to be converted to "I", and you don't want to waste your time converting all of them, just skip it and focus on more important issues in the post.

Comment: I found a solution to your problem. It only capitilizes an i that is surrounded by 2 spaces. For exaample, i would be capitilized, while "i" would not be.

Comment: Live example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_y5CUzS6rN0S6lDBDRq2lr_6a8dvJpOHwk3K6gZJWhA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @TheOneWhoMade I can't access the document.

Comment: @TheOneWhoMade What about "  i  " ("i" surrounded with two spaces, or maybe three? or four?)?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure that's a good idea. Although it would probably be beneficial in most cases, it could be very confusing in the few cases where there would be false positives. [Maroun's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/362944/4284627) mentions one of the cases where there would be false positives. If you want another example of a false positive, look at the second sentence in the second paragraph of this answer. You could always surround the "i" with backticks or quotation marks, but sometimes that's not really appropriate, and sometimes the poster would simply not think of it.

Even though I don't think this specific feature would be good, I do agree with the problem that it's trying to solve. A better solution would be to show a warning when the post contains an uncapitalized i. It might be less effective, but it wouldn't cause any problems with false positives. The good thing about warnings instead of blocking content or silently replacing it is that in the case of false positives, the user will know that they're using proper grammar and can just ignore the warning.

Here is a suggestion of how the warning could be worded (this is just a suggestion, there are probably better ways to word it):

> It looks like the pronoun "I" is uncapitalized in your post, which is grammatically incorrect.
>
> While we don't require your grammar to be perfect, we would appreciate if you make an effort to use proper grammar. Questions written with proper grammar are nicer to read so answerers are more likely to be interested in putting effort into answering them.

This message is specific to questions, but it could easily be reworded to fit answers too. The part about getting better answers could make the warning more effective because people asking questions want answers, and are more likely to put effort into grammar if they understand that that will give them better answers.

Similar warnings could also be triggered by other things that could indicate incorrect grammar, like sentences beginning with small letters, common spelling mistakes, etc.

Comment: A will think of posting a request for a warning then.

Comment: Though there is a [userscript by SOCVR](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/UserScripts#magic-editor) that handles stuff like lower-case `i`'s. Of course not perfect either, but it helps editors