# Banner/Error when a user makes too many posts without caps

Tags: feature-request

We all want to waste as little time as possible (well, most of us). What I have seen is that a good chunk of users do not capitalize the noun "I". What I am asking, as some of those on my [other question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362943/auto-capitalization-of-the-noun-i-on-post-submit) have said that it could be a good idea for a banner or error to be displayed if

> "The system has detected that too many of your questions do not have proper grammar/caps/spelling. Please go back and review your questions."

This would be very similar in effect to the block on "not well received" questions. This could be beneficial as it saves the person attempting to answer the question spend a lot less time *reading* the post and be able to spend more time on the question *itself*. What do you (users/mods) think?

Comment: In general, questions posted without proper grammar or capitalization tend to get downvoted. If you start out with downvoted questions, you get presented with a warning that too many of your recent questions were of poor quality. That would seem to hit almost all of these cases.

Comment: Well, if we do it this way, it would prevent them from getting non-well received questions in the first place. They would have to stop and think. @BradLarson

Comment: ***I*** seriously dislike this FR, ***I*** do so much as ***I*** am possible to do. Just edit that stuff if it's like _pearls you found in the sand_ and be happy.

Comment: No, don't do this. I've seen plenty of questions that were okay or even good questions, but writer lacked experience with English language and didn't use proper capitalisation. I don't want to waylay such questions with another roadblock, not when it is easy enough for me to clean up the grammar and spelling.

Comment: Do people actually downvote posts for not being properly capitalized? i mean, other than when the entire post is written in capslock.

Comment: Also, if the person's first language isn't English then they don't necessarily know what they did wrong. In that case, "Your grammar is incorrect", doesn't help because they still don't know what to fix.

Comment: `the noun "I"` "I" is a pronoun, not a noun, my friend.

Comment: @DavyM Good catch!

Comment: I second that ... actually helping them get their questions answered. @MartijnPieters

Answer (score 8):

Grammar is a funny thing around here.  We actually do require that questions have good grammar and good sentence structure, and we also *permit* anyone to edit the question if they feel like it isn't well-structured.

So this paradoxical scenario in which it's okay to downvote the OP for not capitalizing the letter "i" in sentences *and* edit the question so that the capitalization and grammar are correct is a bit wonky.

Let's boil this down to a finer essence:  what would this actually be meant to ***accomplish***?

- Are we trying to **encourage people** to actually include the correct grammar in their question?
- Are we trying to **discourage people** from posting unless they have correct grammar?

If it's #1, then downvoting doesn't seem exactly right.  It's what we do, but it doesn't feel right.  It's simpler to edit the question into shape if you feel like it's a good question in spite of its flaws.

If it's #2, then that's a *horrible* way to go about it.  A good question is still a good question even if the grammar is a bit rough.  I've edited hundreds of questions into shape in that vein.

You should look more to figure out why you want this change to be implemented rather than looking to see if anyone agrees with your implementation.  People may agree, but if your ultimate end goal doesn't make sense, then it's likely not going to be done.

Comment: I'd like to draw a narrow boarder between users trying to post leet code or nerd pidgin, and innocent non native speakers making spelling mistake though.